# CSS3 transform property Internet Explorer 10

Tags: css, transform, explorer

Is it any problem with transform in Internet Explorer 10?

I have this simple code and I can't see the effect (I have Internet Explorer 10)

This is the CSS:

```
img:hover{
            -webkit-transform: scale(2.5,2.5);
            -moz-transform: scale(2.5,2.5);
            -o-transform: scale(2.5,2.5);
            -ms-transform: scale(2.5,2.5);
             transform: scale(2.5,2.5);
         }
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125" alt="Castillo Valencia de Don Juan">
```

You can see the example [here](http://especiales.grupojoly.com/resumen2013/prueba.php)

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Try -ms-transform [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

Comment: @Farla: He did.  Also, http://w3fools.com

Comment: it seems to be working just fine here...

Comment: I've used it: -ms-transform: scale(2.5,2.5);

Comment: So... what could be the problem? The IE version I have?

Comment: Works (tested) in IE9/10/11

Comment: Glups... So now i'm really lost, cause I don't know where the problem is